# Get Joomla parent-category ID

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I got the article ID and category ID but couldn't get the parent category ID.

How do I proceed?

Article ID:

```
<?php $id = (int)JRequest::getVar('id'); echo $id; ?>
```

Category ID:

```
<?php $catid = JRequest::getInt('catid'); echo $catid; ?>
```

I want to find out the parent-Category ID.

Answer (score 3):

If you looking for parent category id of a category then you can try this -

```
$category = JTable::getInstance('category');
$category->load($catid);
echo $category->parent_id;
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me have a look at it :)

Comment: Within an article default template, this worked for me:

`$category = JTable::getInstance('category');

$category->load($this->item->catid);

echo $category->parent_id;`